# Using selenium to find div with multiple classes used elsewhere on the site. (python)

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, pycharm

So basically I have something like this...

```
<div class="123">ex1</div>
<div class="456">ex2</div>
<div class="789">ex3</div>
<div class="100">ex4</div>
<div class="123 456 789 100">ex5</div>
    <a aria-label="Title" class="the same problem"></a>
```

And I want to select the 5th div, without selecting other 4.

I've seen some people doing this:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.123.456.789.100"));
```

But when I tried to install the org module I got **"Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement org"** error.

So I found this:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='123' or @class='456' or @class='789' or @class='100']")
```

But I also got

> "selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such
> element: Unable to locate element:
> {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@class='123' or @class='456' or
> @class='789' or @class='100']"}"

error.

I've done my research, nothing helped so I decided to ask here.

Also I want to get the aria-label text from that "a" object later on, it has the same problem I described before. I'll probably figure it out myself tho. For now I really want to know how to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, what language do you use?
by import org. it's java if i'm not mistaken, then you're using python.

to find element in python, just:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://you_site')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="123 456 789 100"]')
```

try this,

Comment: Thanks, this worked... It says "python" in the title but I can see why that may be unclear.